# how mapping an IOS call back to this method in codenameone with native interface

Tags: codenameone

//Codenameone side java
public static void onNativeCallBack(String p, int status) {

```
}
```

How can I create a mapping from obj-c code to java code in codenameone. I was reading this thread
https://www.codenameone.com/developer-guide.html#_native_interfaces
but I can't understand very well.

this the correct way?
com_xxxxxxx_xxxxxx_utils_NativeIOSRequestPermission_onNativeCallBack__java_lang_String_int(//I can't understand how to mapp);

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a static public method callback in the Java side then send an "Include Source" build and open the project in xcode. It will make understanding this much easier.

Generally, yes this should map reasonably well. You could open the C header file and look at the definition of the callback function to understand the signature.